# Python JSON loop only printing values of last object

Tags: python, json

I am attempting to loop through a json-web service to write attributes from each object to a database.  Below is my code-snippet and output json.  I would like to write values from each object to a database, i.e. values from each item. Now my code snippet is only printing values from the last object, so "1" for ItemCount.

```
"ListOfLa311ElectronicWaste": {
                        "La311ElectronicWaste": [
                            {
                                "CollectionLocation": "Gated Community/Multifamily Dw",
                                "DriverFirstName": "",
                                "DriverLastName": "",
                                "ElectronicWestType": "Microwaves",
                                "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "Curb",
                                "IllegallyDumped": "N",
                                "ItemCount": "3",
                                "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                                "OtherElectronicWestType": "",
                                "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                                "TruckNo": "",
                                "Type": "Electronic Waste",
                                "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "",
                                "LastUpdatedBy": "",
                                "Name": "021720151654176711"
                            },
                            {
                                "CollectionLocation": "Gated Community/Multifamily Dw",
                                "DriverFirstName": "",
                                "DriverLastName": "",
                                "ElectronicWestType": "Televisions (Any Size)",
                                "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "Curb",
                                "IllegallyDumped": "N",
                                "ItemCount": "6",
                                "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                                "OtherElectronicWestType": "",
                                "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                                "TruckNo": "",
                                "Type": "Electronic Waste",
                                "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "",
                                "LastUpdatedBy": "",
                                "Name": "021720151654176722"
                            },
                            {
                                "CollectionLocation": "Gated Community/Multifamily Dw",
                                "DriverFirstName": "",
                                "DriverLastName": "",
                                "ElectronicWestType": "VCR/DVD Players",
                                "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "Curb",
                                "IllegallyDumped": "N",
                                "ItemCount": "1",
                                "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                                "OtherElectronicWestType": "",
                                "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                                "TruckNo": "",
                                "Type": "Electronic Waste",
                                "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "",
                                "LastUpdatedBy": "",
                                "Name": "021720151654176723"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
```

Code:

```
  f2 = open('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DetailView.json', 'r')

        data2 = jsonpickle.encode( jsonpickle.decode(f2.read()) )

        url2 = "https://myla311.lacity.org/myla311router/mylasrbe/1/QuerySR"
        headers2 = {'Content-type': 'text/plain', 'Accept': '/'}

        r2 = requests.post(url2, data=data2, headers=headers2)

        decoded2 = json.loads(r2.text)

        for sr in decoded2['Response']['ListOfServiceRequest']['ServiceRequest']:
            SRAddress = sr['SRAddress']
            latitude = sr['Latitude']
            longitude = sr['Longitude']

            for ew in sr["ListOfLa311ElectronicWaste"][u"La311ElectronicWaste"]:
                CommodityType = ew['Type']
                ItemType = ew['ElectronicWestType']
                ItemCount = ew['ItemCount']
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question.  Why do you say about only printing from the last object?  I don't see any print statement or a statement that writes to the database.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking or how the code you posted relates.

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to discover why the ItemCount was printing for the last JSON object in LAEwaste311, which was a quantity of 1.

My initial print statement was `print ItemCount`

I was able to solve this with `print  ew['ItemCount'] which returned 3, 6, 1 of each item as noted in the above JSON.